# How to find to the latest gradle version and the wrapper

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Hi I'm fairly new to android development.  I have a question regarding the Gradle version and the distribution url in gradle-wrapper.properties

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"


distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

So every once a while I need to update gradle version (because android studio requires it).  How do I find the new version number.  Sometimes I need to update the gradle wrapper too, so how do I find the new distributionUrl that works with new gradle version?

It feels no one talk about this part of the android development and there isn't good documentations especially after google io

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gradle Wrapper version can be changed by executing `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.9` as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:upgrading_wrapper). This will automatically update the `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`. If you want to manually set the `distributionUrl`, you can rely on the URL conforming to the same pattern as in your example. In other words, you can simply change the part of the URL that specifies the version (`4.4` in your example) to the desired version. Check the [repository](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/), you will see that all releases are available at URLs that conform to the pattern `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-X.Y-DISTRIBUTIONTYPE.zip` (with capitalization indicating variable parts). The list of releases are also available in more reader-friendly format on the ["Releases" page](https://gradle.org/releases/) of the Gradle Website.

Comment: While 4.9 may be relevant at time of posting this answer, using the "current" gradle link : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html will show the relevant 'current' version number at a future time

Comment: @RachelGallen not sure I get what exactly you're saying. The wrapper needs an argument specifying what gradle version it should behave as, and there is no option to specify "current" or "newest" as far as I know, so I just put in the version number for the current version as of today. Sure, when you *install* Gradle, homebrew or similar can be left to pick the current version, but as for the wrapper task, by default it "[...] [picks the exact same Gradle version that was used to generate the Wrapper files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)".

Comment: You posted a link to 4.9 . This link will be obsolete when an SO user looks at this answer at a later date. However the link to the current version will cite the then-current version. That is my point

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks, I got your point now, I hope. Changed https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html to  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: Hi Janus, with the default android studio project template the classpath gradle version and the distribution url version are not the same, should they be? if not how do you find the corresponding version?

Comment: @CharlieWu By "the classpath Gradle version", do you mean the Android Gradle plugin? Check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) reference; it contains a table that lists the minimum Gradle version for each version of the Android Gradle Plugin. TL;DR Android Gradle Plugin version != Gradle Version.

Comment: Janus, Thanks, that was the key