# Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[18.0.0]

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio, build.gradle

I am relatively new to Flutter and the project was working 2 days ago.
When I tried to run it today, and I met with this error.
This is the error I'm facing.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[18.0.0].
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.0
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:18.0.0
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:18.0.0
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.0
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:18.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.0
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

This is the code for my app\build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.project"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

I tried updating firebase-bom and google-services but was still facing the same problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you put `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'` in android/build.gradle?

Comment: I did. I was using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'` but even after updating, it did not work.

Comment: facing exactly same issue.

Comment: Any workaround?

Comment: Facing the same issue from a long time

Comment: @DhanrajVerma Try the answer by MrZero. It worked for me. If it still doesn't work for you, then a temporary workaround is to turn off your WiFi while building the app. You can turn it back on afterwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in gradle-wrapper.properties change distributionUrl to

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip

Comment: For future readers, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940013/how-to-find-to-the-latest-gradle-version-and-the-wrapper) for more info on what this is and how to get the current version

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I am using dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }

Comment: I have similar issue. I am using dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    } What should I use for distributionUrl ?

Answer (score 3):

Delete this, it's added by the firebase plugin

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

And
Set the gradle version to 4.1.0

And the distrubution url
`distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip`

Comment: Thanks, it's work like a charm. You make my day!!

Comment: worked for me with the additional step of changing `compileSdkVersion 28` to `compileSdkVersion 31`